# Mean vs Median that is the?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, calc

I have a number of select statements which calculate fields such as sums, division and also averages. However I am now needing to include a median based on the query, as well as a mean(avg). The table contains 50,000 rows in the MSSQL database, so in the same query return I need to have the results return for each line.

I know there is not a Median formula in SQl, well not that I am aware of. I am using SQL 2012. So if anyone has an idea, I would welcome your thoughts, as I can not be the only person to come up against this.

Example would be something like this

```
Select 
     Round (AVG ([LENGTH]),2) as Length_X,
     Round (Median ([LENGTH]),2) as Length_median,
```

I understand Median is not an accepted sql statement, so just for demo purposes to get my point across

Cheers

Comment: "I can not be the only person to come up against this." And yet you still decided to ask this question. :)

Comment: Median is the same as 50th Percentile. Percentile exists as a function from 2012 onwards

Comment: [Some ways are better than others](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median).

Comment: Not very helpful Aquinas, but hey, life always needs a laugh

Comment: Thanks Jamiec - I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have numeric data, then there is a "median" function.  [It is just spelled differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-disc-transact-sql):

```
select percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by ??) over ()
```

or

```
select percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by ??) over ()
```

(The difference between the two is subtle and probably doesn't matter for most purposes.)

It is, unfortunately, not an aggregation function, so it is often used in a subquery.